# Angular2 module has no exported member

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular2-modules

For a website with authentication in Angular2, I want to use a component of the authentication submodule in the main app component. However, I keep getting the following error:

`app/app.component.ts(3,10): error TS2305: Module '"<dir>/app/auth/auth.module"' has no exported member 'SigninComponent'.`

even after exporting SigninComponent.

The project folder structure is as shown below:

[image]

**app/auth/auth.module.ts:**

```
import { NgModule }       from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule }   from '@angular/common';
import { FormsModule }    from '@angular/forms';

import { RegisterComponent }    from './components/register.component';
import { SigninComponent }    from './components/signin.component';
import { HomeComponent }    from './components/home.component';

import { AuthService } from './services/auth.service';
import { AuthHttp } from './services/auth-http';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
      CommonModule,
      FormsModule
  ],
  declarations: [
      RegisterComponent,
      SigninComponent,
      HomeComponent
  ],
  providers: [
      AuthService,
      AuthHttp
  ],
  exports: [
      RegisterComponent,
      SigninComponent,
      HomeComponent
  ]
})
export class AuthModule {}
```

**app/auth/components/signin.component.ts:**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { AuthService } from '../services/auth.service';

@Component({
    selector: 'signin',
    templateUrl: 'app/auth/signin.html'
})
export class SigninComponent {
    ...
}
```

**app/app.component.ts:**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Router, RouterOutlet } from '@angular/router';
import { SigninComponent, RegisterComponent } from './auth/auth.module';
import { AuthHttp } from './auth/services/auth-http';
import { AuthService } from './auth/services/auth.service';

@Component({
    selector: 'myapp',
    templateUrl: 'app/app.html'
})

export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
    ...
}
```

**app/app.module.ts:**

```
import { NgModule }      from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { FormsModule }   from '@angular/forms';
import { HttpModule }    from '@angular/http';
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AuthModule } from './auth/auth.module';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

import { AuthService } from './auth/services/auth.service';
import { AuthHttp } from './auth/services/auth-http';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
      AppComponent,
      AuthService,
      AuthHttp
  ],
  bootstrap: [ AppComponent ],
  imports : [
      BrowserModule,
      FormsModule,
      HttpModule,
      AuthModule,
      AppRoutingModule
  ],
  providers: [
      AuthService,
      AuthHttp
  ]
})
export class AppModule {
}
```

Comment: Try adding SigninComponent in declaration of app/app.module.ts

Comment: You may have some error in that module.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You do not need the line:

```
import { SigninComponent, RegisterComponent } from './auth/auth.module';
```

in your `app.component.ts` as you already included the `AuthModule` in your `app.module.ts`. `AutModule` import is sufficient to use your component in the app.

The error that you get is a TypeScript error, not a Angular one, and it is correct in stating that there is no exported member, as it searches for a valid EC6 syntax for export, not angular module export. This line would  thus work in your `app.component.ts`:

```
import { SigninComponent } from './auth/components/signin.component';
```

Comment: this solved the issue thanks; the fact that the typescript compiler needs an explicit import feels however like the angular app is not fully modular...

Comment: This answer will work but it "hard-codes" the reference to a specific location within the module.  I've found a better way is to declare the export at the bottom of the module after export class module: `export class AuthModule {}` `export * from './components/signin.component';`

Answer (score 58):

Working with atom (1.21.1 ia32)... i got the same error, even though i added a reference to my pipe in the app.module.ts and in the declarations within app.module.ts

solution was to restart my node instance... stopping the website and then doing **ng serve** again... going to localhost:4200 worked like a charm after this restart

Comment: I was busting my brain over the error from the original question here, until I came by this answer... running "ng serve" again made this error go away! Thanks

Comment: This worked for me too, but not sure about what is this strange behaviour. Maybe there is some issue with change detection scheme, again, not sure though.

Answer (score 10):

Also some of common cases :

maybe you export class with "default" prefix like so

```
export default class Module {}
```

just remove it

```
export class Module {}
```

this is solve the issue for me

Comment: What is the meaning of default keyword there? I also saw some examples with default keyword in some articles.
If it creates problems for export, is there any real scenario where default keyword would be useful?

Comment: by adding the default keyword you tilling the route this will be the default Module incase i'm not referring a Module in the route class by using #Module name

Answer (score 7):

For me such issue occur when I had multiple `export` statements in single `.ts` file...

Answer (score 6):

This error can also occur if your interface name is different than the file it is contained in. Read about ES6 modules for details. If the `SignInComponent` was an interface, as was in my case, then

```
SignInComponent
```

should be in a file named `SignInComponent.ts`.

Answer (score 4):

I got similar issue. The mistake i made was I did not add service in the providers array in app.module.ts.
Hope this helps, Thank You.

Answer (score 2):

I was facing same issue and I just started app with new port and everything looks good.

`ng serve --port 4201`

Answer (score 0):

I had the component name wrong(it is case sensitive) in either app.rounting.ts or app.module.ts.

Answer (score 0):

In my module i am exporting classes this way:

```
export { SigninComponent } from './SigninComponent';
export { RegisterComponent } from './RegisterComponent';
```

This allow me to import multiple classes in file from same module:

```
import { SigninComponent, RegisterComponent} from "../auth.module";
```

PS: Of course @Fjut answer is correct, but same time it doesn't support multiple imports from same file. I would suggest to use both answers for your needs. But importing from module makes folder structure refactorings more easier.

Answer (score 0):

For my case, I restarted the **server** and it worked.