# Angular4 give has no exported member( Failed to compile)

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I am implementing one demo project in Angular4 and I am also new in this(Angular4). I have seen one link,[Angular2 module has no exported member](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41264962/angular2-module-has-no-exported-member), But I am not able to solve this problem.

**app.module.ts**

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { VideoListComponent } from './training/video-list.component';  
import { HomeComponent } from './training/home.component';     
import { AddVideoComponent } from './training/add-video.component';
import { AboutusComponent } from './training/aboutus.component';


@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    VideoListComponent,
    HomeComponent,      
    AddVideoComponent,
    AboutusComponent        
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    HttpModule,
    FormsModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    RouterModule.forRoot([
      {path: 'home', component:HomeComponent},     
      {path: 'videos', component:VideoListComponent},          
      {path :'newvideo',component:AddVideoComponent},
      {path: 'aboutus', component:AboutusComponent},
      {path: '', redirectTo:'home',pathMatch:'full'},
      {path: '**', redirectTo:'home',pathMatch:'full'}
    ])
  ],    
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

**aboutus.component.ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
console.log('It works here');
@Component({
    moduleId: module.id,
    templateUrl: 'aboutus.html'
})

export class AboutusComponent {
    s: string = "Hello";
    constructor() {
        console.log(this.s)
    }
}
```

I want to add **AboutusComponent** than it is giving compile failed.

***I am sharing my directory structure***
[image]

***It give me some error in browser(in below screen shot).***
[image]

I want to add new module in angular4
Please share your idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have missed the Component Selector in the `AboutusComponent`.

It should be

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
console.log('It works here');
@Component({
    selector: 'aboutus', // the selector is missing in your component
    moduleId: module.id,
    templateUrl: 'aboutus.html'
})

export class AboutusComponent {
    s: string = "Hello";
    constructor() {
        console.log(this.s)
    }
}
```

Comment: AFAIK `selector` is optional property. The default is `ng-component`

Comment: @yurzui i may be wrong on this but i have no clue id selector is optional , there is nothing else that catches my eye here in the images

Comment: @yurzui now thats something i couldn't spot bow down

Comment: @RahulSingh. I putted your code but same problem is comming.

Comment: @VSH Do you have a github repo to reproduce?

Comment: can you reproduce this problem in a plunker or on Stackblitz

Comment: @RahulSingh. I will post on Stackbitz. I don't have account on it. It will take time for me.

Comment: @RahulSingh I am confused. But when I putted selector. Than It is working. I don't know.   Confused!!!!. But my problem is solved.

Comment: @VSH great but i dont feel that the selector is optional , ny documentation on this will be great . i could get only this https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/1662 as a document

Comment: @yurzui any reference to if is optional will be great as i had asked few members on gitter and they are with the opinion that it is not optional

Comment: https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/packages/core/src/metadata/directives.ts#L112

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mwrnwg?file=app%2Fhello.component.ts I removed selector from HelloComponent

Comment: We usually can omit it if component is created dynamically Because in other cases we need to know the exact selector

Comment: @yurzui but here the components are not created dynamically are they ?

Comment: But it doesn't mean that we have to specify selector

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/157215/discussion-between-rahul-singh-and-yurzui).

Comment: I am researching. And I will reach you again with solution.