# error TS2304: Cannot find name 'data' when trying to make infinte scroll using angular and ionic

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

I am using ionic 4

I am trying to make an ion-infinite scroll i am getting error as 
[ng] ERROR in src/app/tab2/tab2.module.ts(6,10): error TS2305: Module '"/home/temporary/merin/new/src/app/tab2/tab2.page"' has no exported member 'Tab2Page'.
[ng] src/app/tab2/tab2.page.ts(22,11): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'data'.

```
<ion-header>
  <ion-toolbar>
    <ion-title>
      Tab Two
    </ion-title>
  </ion-toolbar>
</ion-header>

<ion-content>
  <ion-button (click)="toggleInfiniteScroll()" expand="block">
    Toggle Infinite Scroll
  </ion-button>

  <ion-list></ion-list>

  <ion-infinite-scroll threshold="100px" (ionInfinite)="loadData($event)">
    <ion-infinite-scroll-content
      loadingSpinner="bubbles"
      loadingText="Loading more data...">
    </ion-infinite-scroll-content>
  </ion-infinite-scroll>
</ion-content>
```

This is my tab2.page.ts

```
import { Component, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { IonInfiniteScroll } from '@ionic/angular';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-tab2',
  templateUrl: 'tab2.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['tab2.page.scss']
})
export class InfiniteScrollExample {
  @ViewChild(IonInfiniteScroll) infiniteScroll: IonInfiniteScroll;

  constructor() {}

  loadData(event) {
    setTimeout(() => {
      console.log('Done');
      event.target.complete();

      // App logic to determine if all data is loaded
      // and disable the infinite scroll
      if (data.length == 1000) {
        event.target.disabled = true;
      }
    }, 500);
  }

  toggleInfiniteScroll() {
    this.infiniteScroll.disabled = !this.infiniteScroll.disabled;
  }
```

}

Comment: Some causes of `no exported member` errors: angular no exported member: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41264962/angular2-module-has-no-exported-member

Comment: i have saved the file tab2.page.ts and named class as export class InfiniteScrollExample

Comment: i am new to angular

Comment: @the head rush https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/infinite-scroll  I am following thiss tutorial

Comment: @sobha there is no data and also your list is empty.kindly follow this tutorial https://devdactic.com/ionic-scroll-performance/